# HOw can I use onchange in jquery

Tags: javascript, onchange

The onchange function is not getting called for below code:

```
<input  id="department" name="department" />
                                

<script type="text/javascript">
$jq("#department").on('change',function(){
        console.log('Inside department onchange');
        validateDepartment();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where have you defined `$jq`?

Comment: Also, what is `validateDepartment()` supposed to do? can you please add your full code

Comment: What is $jq ? ...

Comment: You should probably use `$` or `jQuery` instead of `$jq`

Answer (score 0):

There is one mistake in your jQuery code. You need to use 'jQuery' instead of '$jq', otherwise it will show an error in the console like "Uncaught ReferenceError: $jq is not defined".

```
jQuery("#department").on('change',function(){
    console.log('Inside department onchange');
    validateDepartment();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have `$jq` as that is not proper syntax.

> Basic syntax is: $(selector).action()

A $ sign to define/access jQuery

A (selector) to "query (or find)" HTML elements

A jQuery action() to be performed on the element(s)

Here is a working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
<input  id="department" name="department" />
  </body>
  <script>
  $("#department").on('change',function(){
        console.log('Inside department onchange');
        validateDepartment()
});
    
    function validateDepartment(){
    var inputdept = $( "#department" ).val();
        alert(inputdept + " Department is valid!")
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a syntax error replace **$jq** with **$**  like this

```
$("#department").on('change',function(){
    console.log('Inside department onchange');
    validateDepartment();
});
```

You can do like this

```
$(document).on('change','#department',function(e){
   // code 
});
```

OR

```
$('#department').change(function(e){
       // code 
});
```

Also you can attach onchange attribute with input field in order to handle change event like this

```
<input  id="department" name="department" onchange="myFunc(this)"/>
```

Hopefully this will help you